# Around the world. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> You can find me in *Australia*.
>
> In *Egypt* I will seem to be on *fire*.
>
> And in *Japan* you may confuse me with a *five*.

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mostly inspired from Jason V's answer, you are

> Ra

You can find me in Australia.

> Right there, Aust**ra**lia

In Egypt I will seem to be on fire.

> The Egyptian god Ra, god of the sun.

And in Japan you may confuse me with a five.

> As Jason said, the Japanese kana Ra looks like a 5
>   [image: Japanes kana Ra]

Comment: It's worth noting that despite the stroke order shown above for the letter, you are very likely see the top dot connected to the rest of the character when it is handwritten, rendering it even more like a 5. :)

Comment: You get it, congratulations! I expected more time until someone finds the answer, but this community never disappoints. @DqwertyC

Comment: Correction: In Egyptian mythology it *is* the sun.

Answer (score 6):

potential answer-

You can find me in Australia.

> You are -Mirka Mora a well known  holocaust survivor that immigrated to Australia following the holocaust

In Egypt I will seem to be on fire.

> This is the only part i am unsure of, but the best connection i can make is Gomorrah - The biblical city that burned because of its sin being burned by the wrath of God

And in Japan you may confuse me with a five.

> This is the reason why i came up with that i did. In the Japanese Hiragana, 'ra' looks much like the number 5 with is one of the original moras which is an intrinsic application of linguistics.